# Time complexity question, i think it is impossible with current data

Tags: sorting, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

The question is :

> . Let A be an array of integers in the range {1, ..., n}. Give an O(n)
>   algorithm that gets rid of duplicate numbers, and sorts the elements
>   of A in decreasing order of frequency, starting with the element that
>   appears the most. For example, if A = [5, 1, 3, 1, 7, 7, 1, 3, 1, 3],
>   then the output should be [1, 3, 7, 5].

the thing is, if we want to know how many time each number from 1 to n, appears we need to run of A which his length is m (m = A.length, because its unknow to us).

with bucket-sort , while m = O(n), its possible.

i think there is a problem in the question, because if m = θ(n), or even m = Ω(n).

so basically i think that without classify what m is, its impossible to achive O(n).

if someone know a way to solve this problem i would be glad.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting is something else. I.e., with the *radix sort* you can possibly gain *O(kn)* time which is closer to the linear if *k* is a constant.

The main concern should be If you can somehow manage to run your
overall summation in *O(N)* time then you will still gain i.e., *O(radixSort) + |O(n)| ~ |O(kn+n)| ~ |O(kn)|* in the end.

If you think an approach like this. Take the elements as keys of a hashtable and their sums as the values of the hashtable.

```
foreach (elements-i in the array){
// element is already in the hashTable
if (hashMap.contains(element-i)){
//take its value (its sum) and update it.
hashMap.put (element-i, hashMap.get(elements-i)+ 1);
}

// element-i hasn't been there
// so put it
else {
// key-value
hashMap.put(element-i, 1); // sum is initialized as 1
}
}
```

This runs in `O(N)` time (Worst case scenario). In your case the elements are not sufficient enough to generate some collisions during the hashing so in fact *hashMap.put* , *hashMap.contains* or *hashMap.get* run in `O(1)` time.

Finally. You can just choose any sorting methods to sort the hash table. And whatever the sorting time complexity produced will be the time complexity for this entire process.

Comment: is there another way beside hashMap ?
the instructor want us to preform this task using bucket/radix/counting sort or some of them combined, basiclly we didnt learned hashMap yet so i dont think it count if i will handle the problem using this method

Comment: There isn't, AFAIK. But if it was a plain array. You need an extra array to store the frequencies of distinct elements. Call it *arrOfFreq[]*. Now you start count each freq. of those distinct elements to put into the array, currently freq. of 7 is 1, and at a point later you encounter 7 again, but now you need to traverse the *arrOfFreq[]*  just to find where the freq. of 7 is stored to increment its value (i.e. on 101th index). Thus, it can run in O(n*m). With the hashtable "updating the frequ. of 7" only runs in O(1) bcause we don't traverse the hashtable but accessing it using the key (7).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that the problem as stated isn’t possible - O(n) time is not sufficient to even read all the elements of the array, which means you can’t necessarily find all the distinct elements in the given time bound.

However, if you assume the array has size O(n), then as you’ve noted this can be done with a counting sort.

You may want to contact whoever gave you this problem to point out that detail. :-)

Hope this helps!